# Window Layout selecter

Tags: window

Is there a package that helps me to choose a predefined layout for an arbitrary number of windows in a frame? I would be perfect if it works in a similar way to the select-layout function in tmux.

**EDIT**

Here is a gif showing how tmux switches between different layouts

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something that will adjust the layout of existing windows (perhaps adding or removing some windows also)?  Or instead, something to open a window layout with *particular buffers*?  Sorry if that's answered by the select-layout reference, I don't know tmux

Comment: I would like to have the first option. I found a example showing what I would like to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that it will works *exactly* the way that you want it, but [emacs-rotate](https://github.com/daic-h/emacs-rotate) could be useful. You may have to add some custom Elisp to serve your specific purposes but check it though.

Even though I have a large monitor, I don't split-windows that much unless it's to watch the output of couple of "consoles".

Comment: yes this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

glad to know that someone is looking for this. I was also inspired by tmux and have wrote an elisp exactly for this purpose .

Please download and install https://github.com/lgfang/elisp/blob/master/tiling.el

Then you can "C-\" to switch among predefined layouts, or 'C-u 4 C-\' to tile the last 4 active windows using a predefined layout.

This is by no means a good elisp since I am not an elisp elite. However, that is one of the fun of emacs: you can add functionalities per your very own needs. Isn't it.